# Как восстановить работу цикла

Tags: python, mysql, база-данных, циклы

Подскажите как мне починить цикл.? 
Моя программа работала в консоли, принимала значение и отправляла в бд.

Сейчас пытался сделать для нее интерфейс что бы легче было с ней работать.

Мой самый лучший результат отправить одно значение, но мне нужно что бы она отправила и снова просила ввода.

Или еще один косяк, он отправлял последнее значение постоянно.

```
 from tkinter import *
import pymysql.cursors
import pymysqlpool


# Подключение к БД
connection = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1',
                             user='root',
                             password='',
                             db='python',
                             charset='utf8mb4',
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor,
                             autocommit=True)





def mycon():
    text = edit.get()
    t1.config(text = text)

x=1
while x>1000000:

    x=x+1

    try:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            # Отправка SQL запроса
            sql = "INSERT INTO `scaner` (`number`) VALUES (%s)"
            cursor.execute(sql, (text))

        # Сохранение изменения 
        connection.commit()

    finally:
            print(text)


    if x==1000000:

        connection.close()

win = Tk()
win.geometry('600x300')

win.title("Отправлялка")

t0 = Label(win, text='Отправим в БД', fg='blue')
t0.config(font=('Verdana', 25))
t0.pack()

t1 = Label(win, text='Заставка Текст', fg='blue')
t1.config(font=('Verdana', 16))
t1.pack()

edit = Entry (win, width = 20, bg = 'gray')
edit.pack()

but = Button(win, text = 'Отправить', command = mycon)
but.pack()


var=IntVar()
rbutton1=Radiobutton(win,text='Водка: 0.5',variable=var,value=1)
rbutton2=Radiobutton(win,text='Водка: 0.7',variable=var,value=2)
rbutton1.pack()
rbutton2.pack()





win.mainloop()
```

Comment: 'x=1' и затем 'while x>1000000:'. Ничего не смущает?

Comment: У меня до этого было по другому. в терминале работал цикл.

Comment: http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/Snimok.1548924434.png

Comment: правильно, потому что до этого у вас было по сути `while x < 1000000:`